# mandatory - optional - or Tree in TeX

Tags: diagrams, trees

Does anyone know how I can build trees like this - in TeX?

[image]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to TeX.sx! There are lots of tree questions and answers on the site, so I would do a search first.  For this kind of tree the tree packages `tikz-qtree` and `forest` should be able to do the job. The tricky part of this diagram is the fact that the third branch has been lengthened to reduce the overall width of the tree. If that's specifically what you need to do, then that's a solvable, but somewhat tricky problem. There's also the issue of the notation of the 'or' nodes.

Comment: @AlanMunn: The `tier` key of `forest` should easily solve the lenghtened-third-branch problem, I think.

Comment: @KevinC Thanks I was editing my comment to suggest that `forest` would be the first choice as package here but ran out of time. Your comment confirms that `forest` *is* the way to go for this kind of tree.

Comment: I'd use `Graphviz` for this task, there are also packages for the LaTeX integration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Next time you ask a question, please remember to make an effort yourself first and post what you have managed even if it is not much. At the very least, you should provide the structure of the document (`\documentclass ... \end{document}`) and the contents of the tree nodes so people do not have to start from scratch in order to help you. I happen to be interested in learning more about `forest` else I would not have attempted to answer your question as it stands. You are much more likely to receive answers if you do not rely on the eccentric interests of procrastinators such as myself!

## Constructing the tree

### Step 1: the basic tree

The first step is to set out the basic tree using `forest`'s notation:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

  \begin{forest}
    [Language workbench
    [Notation
        [Textual
          [Symbols]
        ]
        [Graphical]
        [Tabular]
      ]
      [Semantics
        [Translational
          [Model to text]
          [Model to model
            [Concrete syntax]
          ]
        ]
        [Interpretative]
      ]
      [Editor
      [Editing mode
          [Free form]
          [Projectional]
        ]
        [Syntactic services
          [Highlighting]
          [Outline]
          [Folding]
          [Syntactic completion]
          [Diff]
          [Auto formatting]
        ]
        [Semantic services
          [Reference resolution]
          [Semantic completion]
          [Redo factoring]
          [Error marking]
          [Quick fixes]
          [Origin tracking]
          [Live translation]
        ]
      ]
      [Validation
        [Structural]
        [Semantic
          [Naming]
          [Types]
          [Programmatic]
        ]
      ]
      [Testing, optional
        [DSL testing]
        [DSL debugging]
        [More DSL debugging]
      ]
      [Composition
        [Syntax/views]
        [Validation]
        [Semantics]
        [Editor services]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following:

[image: initial tree]

### Step 2: fix the alignment of tiers

As noted in Kevin C's comment on your question, we can get the 'Editor' node to align with the 'Concrete syntax' node using `tier=`:

```
...
            [Concrete syntax, tier=edits]
          ]
        ]
        [Interpretative]
      ]
      [Editor, tier=edits
...
```

This aligns the nodes correctly but there's a problem:

[image: problem]

This is because the `tier` alignment is moving the 'Editor' node 'too far' from where it would usually be and `forest` loses track of what is going on. (I'm sure there is a more technically sophisticated explanation but this is how I think of it.)

We can help `forest` out by using the `phantom` key to create some invisible nodes. These don't get drawn but they help with the spacing. We'll base a phantom subtree on the 'Validation subtree' and insert it before the 'Editor' subtree:

```
...
      [Semantics
        [Translational
          [Model to text]
          [Model to model
            [Concrete syntax, tier=edits]
          ]
        ]
        [Interpretative]
      ]
  [Validation, phantom
    [Structural, phantom]
    [Semantic, phantom
      [Naming, phantom]
      [Types, phantom]
      [Programmatic, phantom]
    ]
  ]
      [Editor, tier=edits
...
```

This is better as we now have space for everything:

[image: tree with phantom subtree]

### Step 3: node appearance

It is time to think about the appearance of our nodes. We would like a box drawn around each one and we'd like sans serif font so we add the following at the start of the `forest` environment:

```
for tree={
  font=\sffamily,
  node options={draw=black!25},
}
```

This gives us:

[image: Boxes and font]

However, we'd like the nodes to be the same height and to accommodate ascenders and descenders even when there are none in that specific node. That is, we want the boxes on a tier to all have the same height.

We add

```
  anchor=base,
  align=center,
  base=b,
```

to the tree options to achieve this.

### Step 4: node positioning and anchors

Things are still not quite right, however:

[image: remaining problems]

Intuitively, there is not enough space between the nodes so things are crossing each other. Moreover, the lines to the children are not radiating from a single point and the tiers seem to be too close together given their breadth.

We can add

```
  parent anchor=south,
  child anchor=north,
```

to get the lines to radiate from a single point. This ensures the line from parent to child always leaves the `south` anchor of the parent and enters the `north` anchor of the child.

To increase the distance between tiers, we add

```
  l sep+=20pt,
```

At this point our tree looks somewhat better:

[image: tree with adjusted node anchors and positions]

### Step 5: thicken the lines

To thicken the lines around the nodes we can add

```
  line width=1pt,
```

but to thicken the lines connecting parents and children, we need to adjust the `edge path`:

```
  edge path={\noexpand\path[line width=1pt, \forestoption{edge}](!u.parent anchor)--(.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};},
```

We now have:

[image: tree with thickened lines]

### Step 6: style the nodes

We need 4 different styles for the nodes: a plain, default style we've already achieved; a 'mandatory' filled circle at the northern anchor; an 'optional' drawn circle with a white centre at the northern anchor; a filled angle at the southern anchor. The filled angle can coexist with the mandatory/optional styles so we'll want to make sure we *append* style options rather than overwriting them.

We therefore add the following style definitions to `for tree` at the start of the `forest` environment:

```
  mandatory/.append style={edge label={node [circle, fill=black!80] {}}},
  optional/.append style={edge label={node [circle, draw=black!80, fill=white] {}}},
  or/.append style={for first={disjunct}},
  disjunct/.append style={
    tikz={\begin{scope}\clip (!u.south) -- (!u1.north) -- (!ul.north) -- cycle; \node [circle, fill=black!80, minimum width=15pt] at (!u.south) {};\end{scope}}
  },
```

The `or` style option needs to be given to any one of the relevant node's *children* rather than passed as an option to the node itself. (Maybe it is possible to avoid this but I couldn't figure out how.) The `optional` and `mandatory` styles are passed to the relevant nodes themselves. For example, here's the 'Semantics' subtree:

```
...
  [Semantics, mandatory, or
    [Translational, or
      [Model to text]
      [Model to model
        [Concrete syntax, optional, tier=edits]
      ]
    ]
    [Interpretative, or]
  ]
...
```

Which produces:

[image: subtree with styled nodes]

### Step 7: add the legend

All that remains is to add the 'legend'. To do this, we'll make use of two `tikz` libraries, `positioning` and `calc`. We'll also define a `legend` style for convenience:

```
\tikzset{
  legend/.append style={line width=1pt, font=\sffamily, align=left},
}
```

The earlier settings only applied to the *tree* so we repeat them in our definition.

We now name one of our nodes so that we can position the legend box relative to that node:

```
...
    [Syntax/views, name=my node]
...
```

Now we can create nodes to hold the legend text and symbols:

```
\node (legend title) [below=of my node, legend] {Legend:};
\node (legend mandatory) [below=5pt of legend title, legend, circle, fill=black!80] {}  ;
\node (legend mandatory text) [right=5pt of legend mandatory.east, legend] {Mandatory};
\node (legend optional) [below=10pt of legend mandatory, legend, circle, draw=black!80, fill=white] {};
\node (legend optional text) [right=5pt of legend optional.east, legend] {Optional};
\node (legend or) [below=5pt of legend optional, legend] {};
\node (legend or text) [right=5pt of legend or.east, legend, yshift=-5pt, xshift=1pt] {Or};
\begin{scope}
  \draw [draw, line width=1pt] ($(legend or) + (5pt,-10pt)$) coordinate (A) -- (legend or.center) coordinate (B)  -- ($(legend or) - (5pt,10pt)$) coordinate (C);
  \clip (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
  \node [circle, fill=black!80, minimum width=15pt] at (B) {};
\end{scope}
```

Finally, we draw the box around the legend:

```
\draw [line width=1pt] (legend title.north west) -- (legend title.north west -| legend mandatory text.north east) -- (legend mandatory text.north east |- legend or text.south east) -- (legend or text.south east -| legend title.north west) -- cycle;
```

And we are done!

## The final code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}

\begin{document}

  }
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      mandatory/.append style={edge label={node [circle, fill=black!80] {}}},
      optional/.append style={edge label={node [circle, draw=black!80, fill=white] {}}},
      or/.append style={for first={disjunct}},
      disjunct/.append style={
        tikz={\begin{scope}\clip (!u.south) -- (!u1.north) -- (!ul.north) -- cycle; \node [circle, fill=black!80, minimum width=15pt] at (!u.south) {};\end{scope}}
      },
      font=\sffamily,
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      node options={draw=black!25},
      edge path={\noexpand\path[line width=1pt, \forestoption{edge}](!u.parent anchor)--(.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};},
      anchor=base,
      align=center,
      base=b,
      l sep+=20pt,
      line width=1pt,
    }
    [Language workbench,
    [Notation, mandatory, or
        [Textual
          [Symbols, optional]
        ]
        [Graphical]
        [Tabular]
      ]
      [Semantics, mandatory, or
        [Translational, or
          [Model to text]
          [Model to model
            [Concrete syntax, optional, tier=edits]
          ]
        ]
        [Interpretative, or]
      ]
      [Validation, optional, phantom
        [Structural, phantom]
        [Semantic, phantom
          [Naming, phantom]
          [Types, phantom]
          [Programmatic, phantom]
        ]
      ]
      [Editor, mandatory, tier=edits
      [Editing mode, mandatory, or
          [Free form]
          [Projectional]
        ]
        [Syntactic services, optional, or
          [Highlighting]
          [Outline]
          [Folding]
          [Syntactic completion]
          [Diff]
          [Auto formatting]
        ]
        [Semantic services, optional, or
          [Reference resolution]
          [Semantic completion]
          [Redo factoring]
          [Error marking]
          [Quick fixes]
          [Origin tracking]
          [Live translation]
        ]
      ]
      [,phantom
        [,phantom
          [,phantom]
        ]
      ]
      [Validation, optional, or
        [Structural]
        [Semantic, or
          [Naming]
          [Types]
          [Programmatic]
        ]
      ]
      [Testing, optional, or
        [DSL testing]
        [DSL debugging]
        [More DSL debugging]
      ]
      [Composition, optional, or
        [Syntax/views, name=my node]
        [Validation]
        [Semantics]
        [Editor services]
      ]
    ]
    \tikzset{
      legend/.append style={line width=1pt, font=\sffamily, align=left},
    }
    \node (legend title) [below=of my node, legend] {Legend:};
    \node (legend mandatory) [below=5pt of legend title, legend, circle, fill=black!80] {}  ;
    \node (legend mandatory text) [right=5pt of legend mandatory.east, legend] {Mandatory};
    \node (legend optional) [below=10pt of legend mandatory, legend, circle, draw=black!80, fill=white] {};
    \node (legend optional text) [right=5pt of legend optional.east, legend] {Optional};
    \node (legend or) [below=5pt of legend optional, legend] {};
    \node (legend or text) [right=5pt of legend or.east, legend, yshift=-5pt, xshift=1pt] {Or};
    \begin{scope}
      \draw [draw, line width=1pt] ($(legend or) + (5pt,-10pt)$) coordinate (A) -- (legend or.center) coordinate (B)  -- ($(legend or) - (5pt,10pt)$) coordinate (C);
      \clip (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
      \node [circle, fill=black!80, minimum width=15pt] at (B) {};
    \end{scope}
    \draw [line width=1pt] (legend title.north west) -- (legend title.north west -| legend mandatory text.north east) -- (legend mandatory text.north east |- legend or text.south east) -- (legend or text.south east -| legend title.north west) -- cycle;
  \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

## The final tree

[image: final tree]